# Custom 403 error static HTML page showing origin IP address in HTML page content

Tags: nginx, nginx-ingress, nginx-location

I m using NGINX version 1.23.3 and I wanna introduce a custom 403 static error HTML page, which dynamically shows the client origin IP address in the HTML page content.
Since I use Kubernetes and NGINX docker image (nginx/nginx-ingress v. 3.0.2) I will use volume mount to mount the static page on NGINX server.

I have tried as follow:

- Using add_header to set the response header and use JS to read the header values and add it to the HTML content --> This only works with response code 200 or 304
- Using sub_filter to replace the HTML content --> This only works with response code 200 or 304
- Using URL query params and read the query params from JS --> This only works with response code 200 or 304

Since it’s an error I want to return the 403 instead of 200.

Anyone can help me with this?

Thank you in advance.